# Unable to understand the flow of the program

Tags: c++

I am unable to understand as to why the switch block is not executed. I am trying to generate random numbers between 0 and 2 using rand() within comp_in() function. I return the number to the main function. Within the main function, I am trying to associate a char to each letter generated. The switch statement is not executed at all. Please help!

```
#include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int comp_in();

    int main()
    {

        char h;
        h = human_in();

        int c = comp_in();
        cout << "c is" << c << endl;

        switch(c)
        {
            case '0' : cout << "Computer's choice is : 'R'" << endl;
                       break;
            case '1' : cout << "Computer's choice is : 'P'" << endl;
                       break;
            case '2' : cout << "Computer's choice is : 'S'" << endl;
                       break;
        }


    }


    int comp_in()
    {
        int s;
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            s=rand()%3;
        }
        cout << "s is : " << s << endl;
        return s;
    }


Output:- 
s is : 1
c is1
```

Comment: Look at it in your debugger and you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: It's good practice to include a `default` block when using a switch statement.

Comment: There's a difference between `0` and `'0'`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `comp_in` function returns *numbers*, but your switch is comparing its result to *characters*. Simply remove the single quotes from each case, making them numbers, and it'll work:

```
    switch(c)
    {
        case 0 : cout << "Computer's choice is : 'R'" << endl;
                 break;
        case 1 : cout << "Computer's choice is : 'P'" << endl;
                 break;
        case 2 : cout << "Computer's choice is : 'S'" << endl;
                 break;
        default: cout << "Computer made a really strange choice: " << c << endl;
                 break;
    }
```

Do note that at some point in the future, you might want to compare the human input with the computer input. Since your `human_in` function returns a character, you're going to have to convert it by using a function like `atoi`.

You can detect bugs like these more quickly if you output some sort of debug message in a `default` case, which I've also included in the code sample above.